# Customise SharePoint Lists' EditForm & NewForm

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, visual-studio, custom-list, list-form, schema

I want to merge the EditForm or the NewForm of two Lists into One.

For exemple :NewForm of List A and NewForm of List B

The List A has an lookUP item from List B. Following the traditional Way , I have to add items into list B and after that I can add items into list A . 
But like this I will swich at least in 4 pages which is annowing.
So My idea , is there a way to have one NewForm at List A which also contain the NewFom of the List B. 
Hope its clear !

Here in Schema.xlm : how can I add the other From ?

Schema.xlm List A:

```
      <Form Type="DisplayForm" Url="DispForm.aspx" SetupPath="pages\form.aspx" WebPartZoneID="Main" />
      <Form Type="EditForm" Url="EditForm.aspx" SetupPath="pages\form.aspx" WebPartZoneID="Main" />
```

Schema.xlm List B :

```
<Form Type="DisplayForm" Url="DispForm.aspx" SetupPath="pages\form.aspx" WebPartZoneID="Main" />
          <Form Type="EditForm" Url="EditForm.aspx" SetupPath="pages\form.aspx" WebPartZoneID="Main" />
```

Look like no Key Here that i can refer to .

Best regards